# What is using of #pragma directive in C#?

Tags: c#

I know `#pragma` allows us to disable compiler warnings; but want to know how to use it in C# code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example before posting a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# code, you should be able to `disable` or `enable` the warning using the `#pragma` directive. The syntax of #pragma is,

```
#pragma warning disable warning-list => To disable the warning
#pragma warning restore warning-list => To enable the warning
```

For eg,

```
// pragma_warning.cs  
using System;  

#pragma warning disable 414, CS3021  
[CLSCompliant(false)]  
public class C  
{  
    int i = 1;  
    static void Main()  
    {  
    }  
}  
#pragma warning restore CS3021  
[CLSCompliant(false)]  // CS3021  
public class D  
{  
    int i = 1;  
    public static void F()  
    {  
    }  
}
```

And one more thing you can do using the #pragma directive is to generate checksums for source files. The syntax for that is,

```
#pragma checksum "filename" "{guid}" "checksum bytes"
```