# Suppress "this.field" code style warning only in constructors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style

Is there any way to suppress Visual Studio's `this.Field` code style warning only in constructors (without individually annotating each and every constructor in my code, I mean) and keep it everywhere else?

Comment: Hi,@Medinoc. You could try and see if the [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#pragma-warning) helps you.

Comment: Hi, @HuiLiu-MSFT. Looks like it won't. It doesn't have the automatically-discriminating factor I'm looking for.

Comment: You could try to see if a code analyzer with a custom rule set (such as StyleCop or Roslyn analyzer) works for you.[Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

Comment: So there's no way in built-in analysers. Given the most common pattern of use for `this.Field` in C#, this feels like a weird oversight.

Comment: Have you tried setting the [Code styles in EditorConfig files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022#code-styles -in-editorconfig-files) to see if it works for the specified code? such as:
[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:suggestion  You may also want to see if the conversation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464889/what-is-using-of-pragma-directive-in-c) helps.

Comment: Enabling `dotnet_style_qualification_for_field` would be a step in the right direction, but would apply to constructors/initializers and other methods alike, indiscriminately. As for using `#pragma` around constructors, that's exactly what I meant by "individually annotating each and every constructor in my code".